# HDInsight Invoke-Hive performance

Tags: performance, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am using Azure HDInsight service and I have created few tables in it.

Each time that I use Invoke-Hive "Query" command in Windows Azure PowerShell, it open a job and it takes around 30~50 second to finish it.

I have the same data on normal centos machine with hadoop+hive on it, and those query take 1~3 second each.

There is any possible to improve the performance on the Azure Hive?

Query example (Run at Windows Azure PowerShell):
Invoke-Hive "select * from Customer limit 20"

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any more details on the hadoop/hive combo plus the data set you are querying and how you have it stored?  There are a variety of reasons this could happen.

Answer (score 0):

HdInsgight SDK queries goes through Templeton which creates a new YARN application to execute the query. You can submit queries through hiveserver for better performance.